# Map Reduce program which Caches results and computes automatically when changes affect input dataset

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have a set of input files which are going through changes. Is there any way by which we can run a Map reduce program which caches results. Also, whenever there is any change to the input files the Map Reduce program automatically runs again and the resultset is altered according to changes to input files? Can we use MR to approach this dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a fair idea that can be done as i can not give code over here

you can do one thing that use flume for the changes in the file and use mapreduce job as the flume sink.

So whenever the content of the file changes flume agent will be triggered and your mapreduce job as the sink of flume will be executed.

this way you can achieve your goal

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Map Reduce is in the realm of batch processing and is not real time, also HDFS is append only file system, if one record out of a billion had changed, than the whole dataset or part file has to be re-written. Not good for near realtime processing and can get very compute intensive if the changes can not be cached in the Mapper and you need to use the Reduce side join.

For the problem you have described it will be better to use a combination of Kafka, Storm and HBase or just HBase depending on how the changes to the file are generated.